# How to match multiline if some string exist while some string don't

Tags: regex

I wanna to match obj number in PDF. I just want the number before "obj" meet the condition that the string following it in the bracket << >> contains /ObjStm.
Desired match:

363 0

364 0

while 2 0 is not my desired obj number. How to reg match it?

> %PDF-1.7
>
> 363 0 obj <<
>
> /Filter
>
> /FlateDecode
> /First 55 /Length 339 /N 8 /Type
> /ObjStm 
> >>stream
>
> somestring fox jupm over dog.
>
> endstream
>
> 2 0 obj <</Type sf >> endobj
>
> 364 0 obj <</Filter/FlateDecode/First 657/Length 1492/N
> 75/Type/ObjStm>>stream somestream.

https://regex101.com/r/wU700E/1

Comment: Please **always** add your programming language (as stated in the tag), e.g. with `.NET` this is reasonably easy.

Comment: Well, `(?s)(\d+ \d+)\s+obj\s*<<(?:(?!<<).)*?\/ObjStm(?:(?!<<).)*?>>stream` might work. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XlNDht/1).

Comment: It works! Thanks. I've spent hours at it for I'm not familiar with regexp.

Comment: But it will not word if there are <<>> s inside <<>>. For example <<somestring <<someothestring>>>> it fails. The string match shoul only contain one "obj".

Comment: (?s)(\d+ \d+)\s+obj\s*<<(?:(?!obj).)*?\/ObjStm(?:(?!obj).)*?>>stream    Work now.

Comment: 363 0 obj<</Filter/FlateDecode<</First 55/Length 339>>/N 8/Type/ObjStm>>stream  
How to catch the number after /Length into a group at the same time(in this case 339)? The key word /Length may appear before or after /ObjStm.

Comment: (?s)(\d+ \d+)\s+obj\s*\<\<(?:(?!obj).)*?(?:\/Length (\d+)(?:(?!obj).)*?\/ObjStm(?:(?!obj).)*?)|\/ObjStm(?:(?!obj).)*?\/Length (\d+)(?:(?!obj).)*?>>stream     works but not smart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if lookaheads are supported (often):

```
^\ *([\d ]+)obj\s+<<(?:(?!>>)[\s\S])+/ObjStm(?:(?!>>)[\s\S])*>>
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/M99LVt/1/).

Comment: ^\ *(\d+ \d+)\s+obj\s+<<(?:(?!obj)[\s\S])+\/ObjStm(?:(?!obj)[\s\S])*>> Is what I needed.